# Dynamicaly change leafletjs tilelayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openweathermap

How can i load new images for TileLayer after changing date in request?

or

How I can update already created TileLayers with new date option?

I have TileLayers from OpenWeatherMap requests is generated with this code

```
openweathermap_overlay = new L.TileLayer(
    "http://maps.openweathermap.org/maps/2.0/weather/{op}/{z}/{x}/{y}?appid={API_key}",
   {
      API_key: key,
      date: date,
      op: op_key
   })
```

In my mind it must be something like here: https://openweathermap.org/weathermap?basemap=map&cities=false&layer=radar&lat=56.9510&lon=24.1064&zoom=5

While you drag date you can see that tiles changing
Of course i have tried something like this:

```
date: getDate(),
```

And this doesn't work.

Great Thanks for every advice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok It was so easy.

```
var url = "http://maps.openweathermap.org/maps/2.0/weather/{op}/{z}/{x}/{y}?appid={API_key}&opacity={opacity}&date="
openweathermap_overlay = new L.TileLayer(
   url+date,
   {
      API_key: key,
      op: op_key
   })
openweathermap_overlay.setUrl(url+new_date)
```